# Why is $0 not in quotes?

Tags: bash

I saw this line
`. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"`

Why is `$0` not inside the quotes?
Or phrased differently: what is the reason for writing it that way and not
`. "$(dirname -- $0)/_/husky.sh"`

Comment: `$( )` starts a new quoting context -- everything in that new context is unquoted until syntax is used to make it otherwise, so quotes inside that context don't end quotes started outside of it. This is one of the key advantages over legacy backtick command substitution syntax.

Comment: On the contrary, `$0` is inside quotes in the first example and it is not quoted on the second example. `$()` introduces a new level of nesting. The quote before `$0` does not close the quote before `$(`, it starts a new quoted string (that contains `$0`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quoted. `$(...)` starts a new quoting context, so a shell executes

```
dirname -- "$0"
```

and the *result* is used in the quoted string

```
".../_/husky.sh"
```